# windows: blue screen on boot, kernel data in page, m2 formatting error, is this a bad SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bluescreenview

After some bad experiences with dualbooting windows and linux (windows updates can destroy the linux bootloader) I've now switched to having separate disks for each OS.
I installed another SSD in my notebook and installed windows on it. The desired operating system can then be booted via the bios boot menu.

This has worked really well for a week but today windows seems to have destroyed itself. I was using Firefox, then suddenly the browser froze. Then the cursor froze, then the system crashed. On reboot I was greeted with a bluescreen and the error message "kernel data in page". Another reboot prompted me to insert a repair medium. Another reboot didn't even get that far, there was simply black and white text `M2 formatting error` (or something similar).

Fortunately, the Linux system still seems to work fine (I'm typing this on it). However, I can't access the windows ssd anymore. Up to now, I could access the windows filesystem from linux. Now it says `unknown error when mounting /dev/nvme0n1p2`

Also fortunately, there is no data loss. Everything is backed up. I am already flashing a recovery usb. But in case a simple 'run repair' doesn't do it and I have to reinstall everything, I wanted to ask: Can you tell me what went wrong here?

I've heard of cases where windows 10 basically kills itself. But the error messages sound like a faulty SSD. And I want to avoid having the same problem again in a week.

Comment: Windows installations do not suddenly do what has happened to your system on a healthy drive.  Use the appropriate tools to check the health of the drive.

Comment: What would be an appropriate tool? @Ramhound